# NullPointerException when trying to set ImageView with Google Static Map

Tags: java, android, android-imageview, google-maps-static-api

I'm trying to set the source of an ImageView to the image located at a Google Static Map's URL. An example of this url would be this... [LINK](http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=37.386052,-122.083851&zoom=13&markers=size%3amid%7Ccolor%3ablue%7C37.386052,-122.083851&path=color:0x0000FF80%7Cweight:5%7C37.40276,-122.06360&size=220x150&sensor=false)

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=37.386052,-122.083851&zoom=13&markers=size:mid%7Ccolor:blue%7C37.386052,-122.083851&path=color:0x0000FF80%7Cweight:5%7C37.40276,-122.06360&size=220x150&sensor=false
```

I have read multiple StackOverflow posts about this issue, and all of those questions have been answered with pieces of code that work for other people but for some reason not me. Here is my code. (I left out pieces that do not have to do with the issue). The NullPointerException occurs at line `mapView.setImageBitmap(result);`

Main Class

```
public class CoffeeResultActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp);
    String userChoice = (String) getIntent().getExtras().get("userChoice");

    //CALL THE ASYNC TASK HERE
    new RetreiveSearchResults().execute(userChoice);

}

class RetreiveSearchResults extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(CoffeeResultActivity.this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Searching for caffeine...");
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... terms) {        

        /*
            .........
        */

        try {


            //GETS IMAGE
            ImageLoadingTask task = new ImageLoadingTask();
                                            task.execute("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=37.386052,-122.083851&zoom=13&markers=size:mid%7Ccolor:blue%7C37.386052,-122.083851&path=color:0x0000FF80%7Cweight:5%7C37.40276,-122.06360&size=220x150&sensor=false");

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   


        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(CoffeeResultActivity.this, businessNames, businessInfo);
        listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        // setting list adapter
        expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        progressDialog.dismiss();   

    }
}

public class ImageLoadingTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... stringURL) {
        Bitmap bmp = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(stringURL[0]);

            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.connect();
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, options);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return bmp;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {

        ImageView mapView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        mapView.setImageBitmap(result);
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

}

}
```

Layout XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="55dip"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lblListItem"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:linksClickable="true"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Can anyone shed some light into this?

Comment: Well, mapView is probably null.

Comment: Well it's an obvious thing but most likely this: `findViewById(R.id.imageView1)` returns `null`. I don't know why because you've got it in your layout but play around with it and it should work.

Comment: AsyncTask must be invoked on the ui thread. But you have it doInbackground

Comment: I put `mapView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);` in onCreate and it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use image loader library as AQuery. you can find a .jar library that you can directly paste on your libs folder. it supports caching too.

an example usage to load an image from url to imageview.

```
AQuery aq = new AQuery(context);
aq.id(R.id.imageview).image(url);
```